# How to write a stack in python by giving a range and using for- loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, for-loop, stack

I was trying to write a stack operation using python 3 and classes where i don't add the elements into the list manually but instead use a range of 0-10.
But i stumble into the problems either l1 is not defined or missing parameters
Please help, below is my code for pushing into a empty list.

```
class Stack():

    def __init__(self):
        self.l1 = []

    def push(self,l1):
        for i in range(0,10):
            self.ll.append(i)
            print(l1)

s = Stack(l1)
print("After stack push operation values are :", s.push())
```

Comment: Multiple problems: `Stack` does not take arguments, use `s = Stack()`. Second problem: you never defined `l1`, so you can't call `s.push(l1)`. `push` does not use `l1` besides from printing it.

Comment: Are you getting errors? Please include the error message in that case

Comment: But, why? Is this a specific homework problem or something? Often I find for beginners it's more helpful to explain what you're trying to accomplish in the abstract, rather than ask for help with some specific approach you're trying to take which may not be right in the first place...

Comment: This was a homework where i needed to use range to push the elements to stack instead of giving elements manually. I didn't know where i was going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a textbook stack implementation to give you a reference:

```
1 class ArrayStack:
2 ”””LIFO Stack implementation using a Python list as underlying storage.”””
    3
    4 def init (self):
    5 ”””Create an empty stack.”””
    6    self.data = [ ] # nonpublic list instance
    7
    8 def len (self):
    9 ”””Return the number of elements in the stack.”””
    10    return len(self.data)
    11
    12 def is empty(self):
    13 ”””Return True if the stack is empty.”””
    14    return len(self.data) == 0
    15
    16 def push(self, e):
    17 ”””Add element e to the top of the stack.”””
    18    self.data.append(e) # new item stored at end of list
    19
    20 def top(self):
    21 ”””Return (but do not remove) the element at the top of the stack.
    22
    23 Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty.
    24 ”””
    25    if self.is empty( ):
    26       raise Empty( Stack is empty )
    27       return self.data[−1] # the last item in the list
    28
    29 def pop(self):
    30 ”””Remove and return the element from the top of the stack (i.e., LIFO).
    31
    32 Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty.
    33 ”””
    34    if self.isempty( ):
    35       raise Empty( Stack is empty )
    36    return self.data.pop( ) # remove last item from list
```

Source: *Data Structures and Algorithms in Python* by Goodrich et al

I think that your example also showed a few errors about how to use classes. If you want to pass an argument to the class when it is being initialized, then that argument needs to be declared like so:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2): # Declare args
        pass
```

And then called like so:

```
s = Stack(arg1, arg2)
```

Next, you mix references to `l1` and `self.l1` in your method definition. I would also add that a variable named `l1` is error-prone because it looks very similar to `ll` (and I think I found just such a typo in your post. I tried to correct your class definition and this is what I came up with:

```
class Stack():

    def __init__(self):
        self.l1 = []

    def push(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            self.l1.append(i)
            print(self.l1)

s = Stack()
print("After stack push operation values are :", s.push())
```

Note that this results in:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
After stack push operation values are : None
```

Comment: What happened to the formatting in your textbook example? Line numbers, no indentation... etc?

Comment: I literally copied from a textbook -- my apologies. I made an effort to fix it just now